# How to solve timeout problem with electron-html-to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm experiencing this timeout when trying to use electron to convert an html file to pdf. I'm running this js app through node.

```
`{ Error: Worker Timeout, the worker process does not respond after 10000 ms
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\code\PDF-Profile-Generator\node_modules\electron-workers\lib\ElectronManager.js:377:21)
at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
workerTimeout: true,
message:
Worker Timeout, the worker process does not respond after 10000 ms,
electronTimeout: true }`
```

I do not know too much about electron. I have not been able to try too much to try to debug it. The js code is meant to generate an html file based on user input, pulling from a github profile. Then, that html file needs to be converted to a pdf file.

My js code is as follows:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const convertapi = require('convertapi')('tTi0uXTS08ennqBS');
const path = require("path");
const generate = require("./generateHTML");
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const axios = require("axios");
const questions = ["What is your Github user name?", "Pick your favorite color?"];


function writeToFile(fileName, data) {
     return fs.writeFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), fileName), data);
};

function promptUser() {
    return inquirer.prompt([
        {
            type: "input",
            name: "username",
            message: questions[0]
        },
        {
            type: "list",
            name: "colorchoice",
            choices: ["green", "blue", "pink", "red"],
            message: questions[1]
        }
     ])
};

function init() {
    promptUser()
        .then(function ({ username, colorchoice }) {
        const color = colorchoice;
        const queryUrl = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
        let html;
        axios
            .get(queryUrl)
            .then(function (res) {
                res.data.color = color
                const starArray = res.data.starred_url.split(",")
                res.data.stars = starArray.length
                console.log(res)
                html = generate(res.data);
                console.log(html)
                writeToFile("profile.html", html)

            })

        var convertFactory = require('electron-html-to');

        var conversion = convertFactory({
            converterPath: convertFactory.converters.PDF
        });

        conversion({ file: './profile.html' }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }

            console.log(result.numberOfPages);
            console.log(result.logs);
            result.stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/profile.pdf'));
            conversion.kill(); // necessary if you use the electron-server strategy, see bellow for details
        });
        // convertapi.convert('pdf', { File: './profile.html' })
        //     .then(function (result) {
        //         // get converted file url
        //         console.log("Converted file url: " + result.file.url);

        //         // save to file
        //         return result.file.save(__dirname + "/profile.pdf");
        //     })
        //     .then(function (file) {
        //         console.log("File saved: " + file);
        //     });

    })
}
init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I had installed multiple versions of Electron (electron, electron-html-to, electron-prebuilt), and the problem was resolved when I deleted the older versions in package.json so only one was left. The assumption is that they were interfering with each other.

So check the installed versions of electron, because the problem might be there rather than your code.